# Android Studio (1.5.1) -- Error: cannot find symbol class / App won't run

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on my first Android application. It's a very simple farenheit/celsius converter, and all of my IDs, methods, and buttons/text fields are perfectly copied out. I triple checked. (I'm following instructions from a video my professor posted.) However, **I'm having difficulty trying to get Android Studio to run the application.**

I've found plenty of questions similar to this one and many of them suggest *synchronizing the gradle files*. So I did. I'm still getting these same error messages:

[image]

---

Here is the app information:

[image]

Code from app/res/layout/content_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="john.testapplication.TestActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_test">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/temperatureEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Enter Temperature" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/temperatureEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From Celsius to Farenheit"
            android:id="@+id/toFarenheitRadioButton"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From Farenheit to Celsius"
            android:id="@+id/toCelsiusRadioButton"
            android:checked="false" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Convert"
        android:id="@+id/convertButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="convert" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code from app/res/layout/activitytest.xml:
(*I thought I was using **Relative Layout**, I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="john.testapplication.TestActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_test" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Again, I was building this app from a video my instructor gave me, so I'm willing to bet it has something to do with my version of Android Studio or settings on my computer as opposed to code itself.

Comment: I know `CoordinatorLayout` but no `**CoordinatorLayout**`.

Comment: Open TestActivity and follow the red underlines. Did you import everything?

Comment: Okay... oops. I was trying to boldface the word inside the code, I should not have done that. Those asterisks aren't part of the problem, that was me. My mistake.

Comment: Yes, everything is imported.

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

Comment: The only red lines I get are from the "cannot find symbol class."

Comment: Select the underlined word, press Alt+Enter, you'll get some options which should fix it.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked! If you want to leave an answer, I can upvote it for you :)

Comment: I still don't know what was the error it fixed :D Why dont you post the answer describing the actual error and its solution?

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: You can always delete the question with all the negative reputation if you retrospectively find it "unworthy". This is just a simple overlook.

Comment: Won't I lose the points from my answer?

Comment: It will be as if the question was never asked.

Comment: Alright, cool! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, with some help from someone on this site, I found a solution. Apparently in TestActivity.xml, I forgot to import these:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
```

Fixed everything. I had assumed it was already all imported. Thanks to Eugen Pechanec for the helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are importing the correct libraries.
Also once correctly imported

```
initialize radioButtons :
RadioButton rd;
```

In the `onCreate` method:

`rd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);`

Comment: Could you clarify where the edits are supposed to happen?

Comment: Typically, to make objects available throughout the activity, initialization can take place right inside of the class. The `onCreate` method would be supplied inside of the `activity.class`.